# how to run seeders using sequelize

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, mysql2, sequelize-cli

I am trying to put values into a table using sequelize.  I installed sequelize-cli globally and I used the command `sequelize seed:create --name my-seed-file` to create seeders folders and I filled the file with the desired values.

When I use `sequelize db:seed:all` to run it gives me the following error

```
Sequelize CLI [Node: 8.7.0, CLI: 4.0.0, ORM: 4.33.4]

Loaded configuration file "config/config.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Run `npm install --save mysql2`

Comment: I have it installed

Comment: @VeenaUppalapati make sure it's listed in `package.json` dependencies. Then you could always delete `node_modules` and re-run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

You can try to install it:

```
npm install mysql2 --save
```

If it doesn't work for you, you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50733063/5732327)