# ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

When using the sequalize   **db:migrate** command I am getting the following error. Looking at some of the previous comments on similar issues people said it is a dependency issue but whenever I run

> npm install mysql2

or

> npm install -g mysql2

I get the same error.

```
larry@DESKTOP-NSSNPRR:/mnt/c/Users/larry/Desktop/node/AAF-NodeJS$
sequelize db:migrate

Sequelize CLI [Node: 10.1.0, CLI: 4.0.0, ORM: 4.37.10]

(node:2241) ExperimentalWarning: The fs.promises API is experimental
Loaded configuration file "db/config/database.json".
Using environment "development".

ERROR: Please install mysql2 package manually
```

Here is my package.json like some of you have asked for.

```
{
  "name": "aaf-website-node",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Nodejs implementation of the achieve anything website",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bin/www",
    "dev": "node node_modules/nodemon/bin/nodemon.js bin/www",
    "test": "jasmine",
    "console": "node console.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AchieveGirl/AAF-NodeJS.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "nodejs",
    "express"
  ],
  "author": "Larry Cherry",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AchieveGirl/AAF-NodeJS/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AchieveGirl/AAF-NodeJS/blob/master/README.md",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "dotenv": "^5.0.1",
    "ejs": "^2.5.7",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "express-ejs-layouts": "^2.3.1",
    "express-minify": "^1.0.0",
    "express-minify-html": "^0.12.0",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "morgan": "^1.9.0",
    "mysql2": "^1.5.3",
    "node-fetch": "^2.1.2",
    "node-minify": "^2.4.1",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "sequelize": "^4.37.10",
    "sequelize-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.4.5",
    "webpack": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.17.2",
    "pryjs": "^1.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file

Comment: I just added it. Hopefully, it helps some.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

So I finally figured out the bug. The issue appears to come from when you are calling the migration from global install of sequelize-cli instead of the locally installed version of sequelize in my project. All I had to do was call the script form the node modules folder and it worked perfectly. I was calling the command this way `sequelize db:migrate` when I needed to call the local installed package this way `node_modules/.bin/sequelize db:migrate`

Answer (score 30):

This one worked for me

`npm install mysql2 --save`

Answer (score 18):

maybe I am late but for whoever looking for answer if and you have mysql2 installed just add this to your sequelize instance to direct sequelize to the right module:

> dialectModule: require('mysql2'),

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.db.database, config.db.user, config.db.password, {
  host: config.host,
  dialect:'mysql',
  dialectModule: require('mysql2'),
});
```

https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/9608

Comment: I'm using Sequelize and mysql2 with AWS lambda. Adding the dialectModeul: requre('mysql2') fixed the issue for me.

Comment: I migrated my project into a nx monorepo and this fixed the issue

Comment: adding dialectModule: require('mysql2'), in the connection config did it for me in 2023. Had this issue on vercel with Node18. Upvoted.

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for in Next.js 13.5.2 in 2023. thanks!

Comment: Adding `dialectModule` worked for me

Answer (score 14):

i installed mysql2 package globally out of my project folder using :

```
npm install mysql2 -g
```

Comment: How is this different from: `npm install -g mysql2` which the person asking the question has already tried?

Answer (score 3):

1. List your global npm packages

   `npm list -g --depth 0`
2. Uninstall `sequelize`

   `npm uninstall -g sequelize`
3. Install `sequelize` in project scope

   `npm install --save sequelize`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me: 
`npx sequelize-cli db:migrate`

Answer (score 1):

You may have run `npm install -g sequelize`. You need to undo this using `npm uninstall -g sequelize` then use this `npm install -g sequelize-cli` instead. This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error while deploying my express app in vercel, below things helped me solve the error.

I have installed `sequelize`, `sequelize-cli`, and `mysql2` locally, specific to the project.

```
npm install sequelize sequelize-cli mysql2
```

Require the mysql2 package in the config file and add it to your configurations, attaching the image below for reference.

[config.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYJMq.jpg)

Hope it resolves!

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to call a specific instance of sequelize (local vs global), so I uninstalled the global sequelize that I had added through yarn `yarn global remove sequelize` and then added it locally to my project `yarn add sequelize`.

npm equivalents would be `npm -g uninstall sequelize` and `npm install sequelize`.

Note in case anyone is going through the same, **I did have mysql2 installed.**

Answer (score 0):

Since version 5.2.0 nodejs comes alongside with an utility called [npx](https://nodejs.dev/the-npx-nodejs-package-runner), which is destined to be used as the "package runner", as it first look packages inside your node_modules you should not have any more troubles running commands with it.

NPM now should be used as a dependency manager instead of a command runner.

You can check differences of both [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605219/difference-between-npx-and-npm)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by running :-

```
yarn add mysql2
```

Comment: Works nodejs 14LTS, just ensure you remove any mysql2 global npm installs, then install it with the above command or its equivalent `npm i mysql2`

Answer (score 0):

`yarn add mysql2` or `npm install mysql2`

reboot your terminal

done!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sequelize with Postgres then the issue will be in your config.json most likely because i ran into the same issue, in config.json my dialect was mysql and it was throwing an error so the correct one is

```
"development": {
    "username": "",
    "password": "",
    "database": "",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "postgres"
  },
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason that you getting an error message to prompt you to install the `mysql2` module is because of the `db:migrate` command is relied on the `mysql2` but as an `optionalDependencies`, so you have to install the `mysql2` module manually

Comment: I have tried installing using npm install mysql2 and npm install -g mysql2. Is there another way to install module manually?

Comment: Use Git to clone the repo

Answer (score -2):

Did you try saving the config.json file before to run sequelize db:migrate? In my case that was the i